# Doing in line editing in VSCode using the Keyboard Only?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode we can create multiple cursors inside a single word or sentence by select alt or option (Mac) and then clicking where we want the additional cursors.

Is there a way to use the keyboard only to create the additional cursors (Instead of having to click)?

Answer (score 0):

From VSCode
[Basic Editing](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics):

> VS Code supports multiple cursors for fast simultaneous edits. You can add secondary cursors (rendered thinner) with **Alt+Click**. Each cursor operates independently based on the context it sits in. A common way to add more cursors is with ⌥⌘↓ (Windows **Ctrl+Alt+Down**, Linux Shift+Alt+Down) or ⌥⌘↑ (Windows **Ctrl+Alt+Up**, Linux Shift+Alt+Up) that insert cursors below or above.

You may use the shortcuts
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
as required.

Comment: I updated the question title.  I meant "in line" editing.  So placing multiple cursors on the same line without using the click.  Thoughts?

Comment: Why can't you use these shortcuts in-line?

Comment: Because when the `down` arrow is pressed it creates a shortcut below the current cursor and when the `up` arrow is pressed it creates a shortcut above the cursor.

Comment: I fear that your case was not foreseen by the VScode developers. If on Windows, you could use a utility such as [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to map your own keys to Alt+Click. Let me know if this solution interests you.

Comment: Well - I guess I don't do it that often so it's not that bad doing option click either - Thanks for trying though :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to create additional cursors, individually, wherever you want in the document, only by keyboard.

But I developed an extension which lets you do exactly that, create cursors and also selections with the keyboard. It's called Keyboard Cursors and Selections (KCS): https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=srares13.kcs

I hope it helps.

Comment: Unless you flesh it out with an explantion or description, its spam.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1207229)

Comment: No problem, I also added a succinct answer under the form of text. I hope it's all right.